# Can someone tell me why i am getting a "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED" error?

Tags: c++11

I have a homework problem that requires me to make a template Stack class. The rest of my code has been tested and works properly, but my reserve function ends up giving me a "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED" error. More specifically it looks like this "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#186) at 0x01200A20. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer."

I have looked at all the other threads i could find where this issue has popped up, but none of them helped solve my issue.

```
template<typename T>
void Stack<T>::reserve(int newCap) 
{

    if (newCap < s || newCap == cap) 
    {
        return;
    }

    T* temp;

    cap = newCap;

    if (cap == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = new T(newCap);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s-1; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = data[i];
    }//When I debugged my program, this block was where the error occurred

    delete[] data;
    data = temp;

}
void Stack<T>::push(const T& val) 
{

    if (s == cap)
    {
        if (cap == 0)
        {
            reserve(1);
        }
        else
        {
            reserve((cap * 2));
        }
    }

    data[s] = val;
    s++;

}
```

All this function should do is assign cap to newCap, and essentially it should point data to a new array of type T with updated storage size. This is so i can push more values into the Stack. When i ran the program it was able to push 7 values into the stack, but it fails within the next 6 calls of push.

Comment: The code you've posted uses the variable `s` in both `reserve` and `push` which is not defined anywhere in the code. Neither is `data` or `cap`. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: `temp = new T(newCap);` --> `temp = new T[newCap];`

Comment: Thanks M.M that helped me get further before encountering another error lol.

Comment: I only posted what i thought was necessary since that is what the guidelines told me to do. should i post the rest?

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code:

```cpp
temp = new T(newCap);
```

will try to give you a *single* object of type `T`, initialised to `newCap`. It does not give you an array of `T` objects that would be suitable for your loop:

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < s-1; i++)
{
    temp[i] = data[i];
}
```

You almost certainly should be using this instead:

```cpp
temp = new T[newCap];
```